# How to use combination of vbKeyShift and vbKeyTab

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two `subForms` on a `mainForm`. `subForm1` contains `ComboBox1` and I have inserted the following code so that if I press `Tab` key it will `setFocus` to `subForm2`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode as Integer, Shift as Integer)
     Select Case KeyCode
             Case  = vbKeyTab
              KeyCode = 0
              Me.parent.subForm2.SetFocus
     End Select
End Sub
```

It works fine. However, when I press `Shift + Tab` I still get the same behavior as I get with above code. In the absence of above code when I press `Shift + Tab` the `focus` is automatically set to the previous `control` in `subForm1` and does not move to `subForm2`. Can someone please help me how can I use combination of `Shift + Tab` in code above so that it does not move the focus to `subForm2` and instead keep the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the logic. I had to first check if `Shift` is pressed so I included `NOT` condition before the code. Now, my code works only when `Shift` is not pressed and retains default Access behavior otherwise.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode as Integer, Shift as Integer)
     If NOT (Shift AND acShiftMask)>0 then

        Select Case KeyCode
             Case  = vbKeyTab
              KeyCode = 0
              Me.parent.subForm2.SetFocus
        End Select

      End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Eh, that code does 100% the same thing as my code, except that your code contains a syntax error.

Comment: Fixed the error. Not sure where I made mistake in using your code. I wouldn't have written this code if yours would work.